# Using postgis geography functions from laravel.

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, postgis

I have a laravel backend to manage a location plugin of sorts. I am using postgresql with the postgis extension. From the postgres shell I am able to execture postgis functions. However, when I try to use the same functions from within my laravel controller I get undefined column errors. As you can see in my examples I am not trying to query anything from the database. I have two points already loaded into memory that I am trying to find the distance between.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)',4326),2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)', 4326),2163));
```

From the shell I get the correct output 
[image: shell output]

However, when trying to execute the raw SQL statement from laravel

```
DB::select ( DB::raw( 'SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText("POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)",4326),2163),ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText("LINESTRING(-72.1260 42.45, -72.123 42.1546)", 4326),2163))' ) );
```

[laravel output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opIlH.png)

I have limit knowledge in both laravel and postgresql so it is very likely I am doing something blatantly wrong. However, I have not been able to find my resources on using postgis from laravel. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Simple: use the first SQL example for the second. The second example uses incorrect quoting characters (`'` and `"`).

As a general rule for PostgreSQL, use only double quotes (e.g. `"MyTable"`) for database objects like tables, column names, etc., and single quotes (e.g. `'a string'`) for string literals, like `text` and `character varying (n)`.

The first example correctly used the string literal `'POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)'`, but the second used `"POINT(-72.1235 42.3521)"` which explains why it was looking for a database object with that name, which obviously you don't.